# (Tensorflow) tf.tensor_scatter_add for two tensors with unknown batch_size

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to use the `tf.tensor_scatter_add` in my loss function as follows:
- tensor `t` of size: (?, 256, 256)
- ndarray `ind` of shape (76,)
- tensor `updates` of shape (?, 76, 256)

I try `tf.tensor_scatter_add(t, ind, updates)` but this does not work. I get this error:

> ValueError: The inner -73 dimensions of output.shape=[?,256,256] must match the inner 3 dimensions of updates.shape=[?,76,256]: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 3 for 'loss/conv2d_15_loss/TensorScatterAdd' (op: 'TensorScatterAdd') with input shapes: [?,256,256], [76], [?,76,256].

How do I reshape `ind` to include the `?` batch size as its leading dimension?